# searching logs for failures using grep with wordlist?

Tags: logs, filter

I am building a wordlist which will contain words like *error,fail,kill,warn,out of,over,too*.....etc.
so that I can filter tons of logs for issues within seconds using grep.

Especially, it's for digging linux logs.

**Found 1:** https://github.com/cornet/ccze

```
static char *words_bad[] = {
  "warn", "restart", "exit", "stop", "end", "shutting", "down", "close",
  "unreach", "can't", "cannot", "skip", "deny", "disable", "ignored",
  "miss", "oops", "not", "backdoor", "blocking", "ignoring",
  "unable", "readonly", "offline", "terminate", "empty", "virus"
};

static char *words_error[] = {
  "error", "crit", "invalid", "fail", "false", "alarm", "fatal"
};
```

**Found 2:**   https://raygun.com/platform/crash-reporting

So, my question is, **is there any wordlist exists already for this kind
of bad words?**

Sorry for the typos.
Thank you.

Comment: So which one you want to filter on? bad, good, error or system?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to use an ALREADY existing wordlist or just roll your own the way @AkhilJalagam did below ? In the former case, please indicate precisely the format of the word list  you'd be keen on using, by editing your question. Notify me with @ followed by my handle if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shell wrapper with wordlist

```
grepbad() {
  grep --color=always -i "warn\|restart\|exit\|stop\|end\|shutting\|down\|close\|\
unreach\|can't\|cannot\|skip\|deny\|disable\|ignored\|\
miss\|oops\|not\|backdoor\|blocking\|ignoring\|\
unable\|readonly\|offline\|terminate\|empty\|virus" $*
}

grepgood() {
  grep --color=always "activ\|start\|ready\|online\|load\|ok\|register\|detected\|\
configured\|enable\|listen\|open\|complete\|attempt\|done\|\
check\|listen\|connect\|finish\|clean" $*
}

greperror() {
  grep --color=always -i 'error\|crit\|invalid\|fail\|false\|alarm\|fatal\|over\|too\|out of\|kill\|exception\|ban\|not' $*
}

grepsystem() {
  grep --color=always "ext2-fs\|reiserfs\|vfs\|iso\|isofs\|cslip\|ppp\|bsd\|\
linux\|tcp/ip\|mtrr\|pci\|isa\|scsi\|ide\|atapi\|\
bios\|cpu\|fpu\|discharging\|resume" $*
}
```

> Screenshot

[image: dmesg]